# Is there any shortcut key for opening browser in windows 8.1?

Tags: browser

My problem is on how to open the browser in windows 8.1 using shortcut keys.
But I searched in google but it not give any correct results.

Comment: Which "browser" are you interested in opening?

Comment: Google chrome browser

Answer (score 1):

You can set a shortcut key for **any** file, including executables such *Explorer*, *Internet Explorer*, *Chrome* or *Firefox*.

1. Right-click on the executable and select *Create a shortcut*.
2. Right-click on the shortcut and select *Properties*.
3. In the *Shortcut key* box, press a key combination you wish to use (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd>)

That said, there *is* a built-in shortcut for *Windows Explorer*, the *file* browser:  <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>.

Comment: OP has since clarified that they are interested in Google Chrome.

Comment: The answer above applies to Chrome, as well as all other files.